# How can i achieve a validation rule to ensure that the values of two columns in a database does not have duplicate using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-validation

This piece of code is working very well but i don't thing its efficient or clean enough if anyone has a better way of doing this please you can always help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5liz.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can do with a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation) and [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique) Rule:

```
class EditVmodelRequest extends FormRequest {

public function rules()
{

    $id = $this->route('id');
    $vehicle = VehicleType::findOrFail($id);

    $unique = Rule::unique($vehicle->getTable(), 'model_name')
        ->ignore($vehicle)
        ->where('model_year', $this->request->get('model_year'));

    return [
        'model_name' => ['required', $unique],
        'model_year' => ['int','required'],
    ];
}
}
```

then in Controller:

```
public function editvmodel(EditVmodelRequest $request, $id)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $vmodel = VehicleType::findOrFail($id);
    $vmodel->update($validated);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i tried using this and it's giving me an unauthorised message

Comment: Unauthorized is from other stuff, not related to this question